# FFMPEG: How to use S3 url in FFMPEG Php

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm generating an image frame from a video in a particular time using FFMPEG Laravel SDK in Laravel 5.6. If I used the local path for video file it's working fine but When **I'm using URL** directly it's giving an error. I want to use the video which is stored in the s3 bucket.

> File not found at path: https:/xxxxx.cloudfront.net/uploaded_videos/filename.mp4

My code as below.

```
$videoFile = env('CLOUDFRONT')."/".$resultStatusValue[0]->video_url;

FFMpegFacade::fromDisk('s3')
->open($videoFile)   
->getFrameFromSeconds($timeToSecond)
->export()
->toDisk('s3')
->save($s3Path);
```

Hereafter generated image should be upload to the s3 bucket.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: solved by `$videoFile = 'uploaded_videos/filename.mp4'` enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If specify the `disk` as `s3` just simply `key` name is enough.

```
$videoFile = $resultStatusValue[0]->video_url;  //= upload/video1.mp4

FFMpegFacade::fromDisk('s3')
->open($videoFile)   
->getFrameFromSeconds($timeToSecond)
->export()
->toDisk('s3')
->save($s3Path);
```

**In Additional** 
if you want uploaded file to public. specify `visibility` on `config/filesystems.php`

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => 'your-key',
            'secret' => 'your-secret',
            'region' => 'your-region',
            'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```